# Angular JS scope variable not available during events

Tags: angularjs, sockets, web

I am trying to update a UI with some periodic data using angular js and web socket, But whenever my event handler is fired , the controller variable is undefined. Here is the code

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mainApp')
        .controller('overviewCtrl', [
            '$rootScope',
            '$scope',
            'commonService',
            'summaryService',
            OverviewCtrl
        ]);

    function OverviewCtrl($rootScope, $scope, commonService, summaryService) {

        this.commonService = commonService;
        this.scope = $scope;
        this.rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.scope.tasks=[];
        this.summaryService = summaryService;
        this.rootScope.connection=new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/echo');
        this.rootScope.connection.onmessage =  this.progress ;

        return (this);

    }

    OverviewCtrl.prototype = {
        cpuUsage: function(){

            return this.summaryService._cpuUsage();
        },
        get serverSummary(){

            return this.summaryService._serverSummary();
        },
        taskList: function(){

            this.scope.tasks=this.summaryService._taskList();
            this.scope.tasks[0].status=0;
            this.scope.tasks[3].status=60;
            return this.scope.tasks;
        },

        progress:function(e){


           var server_message = e.data;
           console.log(server_message);
           this.scope.tasks[0].status=e.data;

     }



    };

})();
```

whenever the progress event handler is called as part of the onmessage from websocket the scope and tasks seems to be undefined . What is the problem?.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the websocket invokes your callback function, it's not bound to `this` anymore. It's just a function, detached from your controller.

My personal opinion is that `this` handling in JavaScript is a nightmare and a huge source of bugs, which is why I very much prefer the traditional way of defining controllers: not using this at all, and bind functions to the $scope if they must be called from the view. You'll never have such a problem if you do that way.

If you persist on wanting to use `this`, then you need to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind, and use it:

```
 this.rootScope.connection.onmessage = this.progress.bind(this);
```